# No such session. PageFactory cannot initialize an element (C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I'm begging you for help!

I use PageFactory to initialize my PageOjbect. One PageObject is invoking by two different classes (also PageObects). When I invoke it from the firs class there is no problem. But when I invoke it from the second class the "no such session" error pops up.

Debuging my code I realized that I have this error when PageFactory doesn't have time to find element's of my page. I tryed to cache all elements, but it didn't resolve the problem.

So, there is my problem class:

```
public class OrderSettingsPage : DriverCover
{
    public OrderSettingsPage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(Driver, this);
    }

    public string HowToDeliver
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.TagName, Using = "h1"), UsedImplicitly]
    private IWebElement _mainHeadline;

    public string MainHeadline
    {
        get { return _mainHeadline.Text; }
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Surname"), UsedImplicitly]
    private IWebElement _surnameTextBox; 

    public IWebElement SurnameTextBox
    {
        get { return _surnameTextBox; }
    }
```

}

A piece of code that shows test steps:

```
        IWebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver();
        MainFunctions load = new MainFunctions(chrome);
        load.NavigateToMainPage();
        load.IfNotLoggedThenLogin();
        load.NavigateToUrl(load.BaseUrl + "books/create");

        BookThemeChoosingPage bookThemeChoosing = new BookThemeChoosingPage(chrome);

        BookFormatChoosingPage bookFormatChoosing = bookThemeChoosing.ContinueWithoutTheme();

        bookFormatChoosing.ChooseFormat();

        OrderSettingsPage orderSettings = bookFormatChoosing.Continue();

        //There is my neck pain!)
        orderSettings.SetOrderSettings(howToPay, howToDeliver);
```

And the bookFormatChoosing.Continue() method:

```
    public OrderSettingsPage Continue()
    {
        WaitAjax();
        _continueButton.Click();

        WaitAjax();
        IList<IWebElement> elements = Driver.FindElements(By.Id("loginButtonIdInBox"));
        MainFunctions load = new MainFunctions(Driver);

        if (elements.Count > 0)
        {
            load.LoginInPopUpWindow();
            WaitAjax();
        }

        WaitForPageLoading();

        int idOfAlbum = DetermineId();
        NavigateToUrl(load.BaseUrl + "order/book/" + idOfAlbum);

        return new OrderSettingsPage(Driver);
    }
```

So, what is wrong? All elements are presented on the page and steps like the following doesn't cause described problem:

```
        IWebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver();
        MainFunctions load = new MainFunctions(chrome);
        load.NavigateToMainPage();
        load.IfLoggedThenLogOut();

        switch (typeOfProduct)
        {
            case ProductType.Cup:
            {
                load.NavigateToUrl(load.BaseUrl + "souvenir/create?productClass=1");
            }
            break;

           ........       
        }

        SouvenirConstructorPage constructor = new SouvenirConstructorPage(chrome);

        OrderSettingsPage orderSettings = constructor.PlaceOrder();

        //The same method doesn't couse any problem
        orderSettings.SetOrderSettings(howToPay, howToDeliver);
```

Error in Nunit:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (NoSuchDriver)
```

Selenium v. 2.42
Chrome v. 37.0.2062.103 
Chrome Driver v 2.10

Comment: This is confusing and you've given way too much code that appears unrelated to the issue. What is the **exact** error and stack trace? Copy that here, not just the message but the **entire** thing. What line does this occur on? How often? All the time? What browsers? What version of that browser? What version of Selenium?

Comment: It appears at different lines. But all lines are using of elements of the page.

I've added extra info for my first post. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Have a read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys the answer for my issue is: never use destructor in a base class. 
In a class that is inherited by others were lines of code such as:

```
 ~DriverCover
 {
      driver.Dispose();
      driver.Quit();
 }
```